# Can _all be removed from elastic search when using kibana4

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

I read that dropping the _all can save a lot of index space, but i do not understand if kibana4 needs this special field or not and everyone seens to avoid that question.

So if i drop the _all field, what might stop working in kibana4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_all` is not required in Kibana. However, if you're doing free text search on the Discover tab, Kibana will issue a [`query_string` query on the default field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#querying-all-field), which is `_all`.

So if you disable `_all` you'll need to explicitly specify the fields you're targeting in your query, i.e. instead of typing `some free text` in Kibana, you'll need to type `content:"some free text" OR title:"some free text"` (i.e. match either the `content` or the `title` field).

Another option is to specify the setting [`index.query.default_field`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#disabling-all-field) when creating your index.

Also see [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4056)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! the index.query.default_field is the key here, changing that to other important field that already exists (message in my case) keeps almost everything transparent for users